# VkKeyScanExA all TCHAR option list

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to make a dll which will simulate a key press. For this I found out you can use an [`INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) in combination with [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). If you know from the start which key to simulate it is easy because you can look in the list of [`Virtual-Key Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) and code it from the start with those keys, but I actually need to be able to change them, so I need it to be dynamically selected. In my research I found [`VkKeyScanExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which is quite nice, because this dll will be used in a native function and from Java I can send a String as the requested key to be pressed, but I ran into a problem, I could not find a complete list of key Strings  to give it like i found with
[`Virtual-Key Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes). Can anyone help me with a source that contains a list like the one here [`Virtual-Key Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) but for [`VkKeyScanExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN)? The problem is that if I use "4", it will use the digit 4, but what if the users whats to use num 4?! That is why a complete list would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, and reading the source code from JavaFX, I found a better way to do it. I can simply get the int value of `KeyCode` from JavaFX and send that in a native function to C++ and not needing to send a String value I also don't need [`VkKeyScanExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) at all. I'm not used to see an int value in this form `0x03`, I though `wVk` can only get a String or an enum value, but for example `0x03` can be used as an int as well.

Here is a simple example in case someone  is having the same use case as me:

a) In java

```
static native void pressKey(int key);

System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Data\\DLL\\Auto Key Press.dll");
pressKey(KeyCode.HOME.getCode());
```

b) In C++

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_package_Test_pressKey(JNIEnv*, jclass, jint key) {
INPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wVk = (int)key;
ip.ki.wScan = 0;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```